# How to register with Eureka,in non-jvm languages(e.g. erlang,php)?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

It seems like that spring cloud sidecar just can  be used to discover Eureka instances,but how to register via spring cloud sidecar?
Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Sidecar starts up it will ping the health_url that is in the configuration to see if the non-Java application is up. If it is then Sidecar registers that app with Eureka. If you read the [Sidecar documentation](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html#_polyglot_support_with_sidecar) in detail it gives you specific examples. The non-Java app doesn't try to register itself.

Comment: So it is!Thank you very much!